# Question about socket.io event hook up in the following code

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In the node.js/socket.io code accompanying [this article](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=1105081&page=5) the following code is used to hook up events:

```
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    var handler = messageFactory[message.messageType];
    $chatMessages.append(handler(message));
  });
```

What is the logic/effect of referencing messageFactory as an array (or at least using [] symbols)? Does it create different handles for different messageType?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the logic/effect of referencing messageFactory as an array (or at least using [] symbols)? Does it create different handles for different messageType?

messageFactory is an object with two methods `chat` and `system`.

I would assume `message.messageType` is either `"chat"` or `"system"`

So `messageFactory[message.messageType]` simply gets one of the two methods.

Then `handler(message)` calls that method.

This is becuase `messageFactory.chat === messageFactory["chat"]`

If you take a look at the server file ("Listing 5: The chatRoom module.") you will see methods returning

```
return {
  messageType: 'system',
  text: originalNick + ' changed nick to ' + newNick
};
```

So the server returns a message object with a `messageType` property thats read on the client, it appears that messageType is only `"chat"` or `"system"`.

That code is basically the OO Command Design Pattern. It's running a different command based on the type of object returned

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that makes sense! I'm still slightly confused about why it's the case that messageFactory["chat"] is the same as messageFactory.chat though. Is that just something about javascript? Do you know where I could find more information on that language feature?

Comment: @joe [`Object properties`](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object.general). Read the garden. It's party of the language